# SQL Padding with zeros(LPAD) in a Database independent way

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, firebird

I have a table like the following :

```
code ---> INTEGER
name ---> CHAR

+------+------+
| code | name |
+------+------+
|  1   |  aa  |
|  2   |  bb  |
|  3   |  cc  |
```

I want to pad with left zeros the code field in this way :

```
SELECT LPAD(code,5,'0') FROM table;
```

This query works well in MySQL but it doesn't work on SQL Server and on PostgreSQL, i'm looking for a query that work on all databases or at least on these four :

- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- MSSQL
- Firebird

without any changes . Is there a solution ?

Comment: Is creating a function named LPAD (and accepting the same args), tailored for each platform, an option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct answer is "do this in your client".
There is no single solution at the RDBMS level

However, for SQL Server *2012* (yes, next release), PostgreSQL and MySQL you can do this:

```
RIGHT(CONCAT('00000', code), 5)
```

- Newer PostgreSQL does have LPAD, SQL Server doesn't
- The various FORMAT functions are incompatible (but again need to wait until SQL Server 2012)
- The RIGHT is consistent, but string concatenation operators are different
- The CONCAT function is added in SQL Server 2012

Comment: You need PostgreSQL 9.1 for CONCAT but at least 9.1 has been released so you don't need a time machine. But +1 for "do this in your client".

Comment: Postgres won't accept the RIGHT function will it?   I've had to use the substring function for this in the past:    substring(code from char_length(code)-4 for 5 ).  Heh, will be quite happy to find out right(character varying,integer) is a usable postgres function in 9.1

Comment: @Tewlfth: 9.1 does http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1):

Kind of weak, but one option is to prepend a number of zeroes to the front, and then take the last x characters from the right.

For example,

```
select '0000000000' || code from table;

will produce
00000000001
00000000002
00000000003
```

Then substring the results would give you

```
select substr('0000000000' || code, -5) from table;

00001
00002
00003
```

I can't recall if the concatenate and substring functions are the same in those four databases. But I guessed that perhaps you are looking for a way to do it that is more generic than what you are already doing, and that might be it. Apologies for the overall ugliness though.

Comment: But `||` doesn't do string concatenation in MySQL, MySQL uses `||` for boolean-or. You need to use CONCAT for MySQL but that isn't in PostgreSQL until version 9.1. Gotta love that SQL Standard thing...

Comment: @mu is too short: thanks; I write in Oracle all day every day and could not recall the syntax. Regardless, I don't actually LIKE this method, but it does work, and if the intent is to get around not having an LPAD function, then this idea should work.

Comment: @mu is too short: the concatenation operator can be changed in mysql and || can be easily set with : SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'; . Unfortunately that can't be configured on SQL Server ... However seems that a solution exist only with concat and Sql Server 2012, PostgreSQL 9.1 .

Comment: @aleroot: Thanks, I didn't know about that one. Gotta' love that SQL Standard stuff eh? Makes life so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

In Firebird 2.5 you can use a query like this:

```
select right('00000' || cast(code as varchar(20)), 5) from table
```

Comment: In addition Firebird has LPAD as internal function since 2.1 and as UDF since 1.5

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible, but my Firebird 3.0 is giving me _"function LPAD is not defined"_, so I am falling back to this clunky snippet. ... Well, I didn't need to `CAST()` as `VARCHAR`: `RIGHT('00' || MY_MONTH, 2)`